# How can I use the 'take(n)' function in Spark 3.4.0 with PySpark to display the top 3 rows of a CSV file?

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark

I am new in spark .I want to use function "take(3)" for getting(displaying) 3 row of my csv file
It is collecting the record correctly

```
raw_data =sc.textFile(“day.csv”)
raw_data.collect()
```

> ['Name,Abbreviation,Numeric,Numeric-2', 'Monday,Mon.,1,01', 'Tuesday,Tue.,2,02', >'Wednesday,Wed.,3,03', 'Thursday,Thu.,4,04', 'Friday,Fri.,5,05', 'Saturday,Sat.,6,06', >'Sunday,Sun.,7,07']

I am reading the csv file like this

```
raw_data =sc.textFile(“day.csv”)
raw_data.take(3) -->error
```

The error statement is

> Python was not found; run without arguments to install from the Microsoft Store, or disable this shortcut from Settings > Manage App Execution Aliases.
> 23/05/27 22:29:16 ERROR Executor: Exception in task 0.0 in stage 11.0 (TID 17)1]
> org.apache.spark.SparkException: Python worker failed to connect back.
> at org.apache.spark.api.python.PythonWorkerFactory.createSimpleWorker(PythonWorkerFactory.scala:192)
> at org.apache.spark.api.python.PythonWorkerFactory.create(PythonWorkerFactory.scala:109)
> at org.apache.spark.SparkEnv.createPythonWorker(SparkEnv.scala:124)
> at org.apache.spark.api.python.BasePythonRunner.compute(PythonRunner.scala:166)
> at org.apache.spark.api.python.PythonRDD.compute(PythonRDD.scala:65)
> at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.computeOrReadCheckpoint(RDD.scala:364)
> at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.iterator(RDD.scala:328)
> at org.apache.spark.scheduler.ResultTask.runTask(ResultTask.scala:92)
> at org.apache.spark.TaskContext.runTaskWithListeners(TaskContext.scala:161)
> at org.apache.spark.scheduler.Task.run(Task.scala:139)
> at org.apache.spark.executor.Executor$TaskRunner.$anonfun$run$3(Executor.scala:554)
> at org.apache.spark.util.Utils$.tryWithSafeFinally(Utils.scala:1529)
> at org.apache.spark.executor.Executor$TaskRunner.run(Executor.scala:557)
> at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1144)
> at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:642)
> at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:1623)
> Caused by: java.net.SocketTimeoutException: Accept timed out
> at java.base/sun.nio.ch.NioSocketImpl.timedAccept(NioSocketImpl.java:694)
> at java.base/sun.nio.ch.NioSocketImpl.accept(NioSocketImpl.java:738)
> at java.base/java.net.ServerSocket.implAccept(ServerSocket.java:690)
> at java.base/java.net.ServerSocket.platformImplAccept(ServerSocket.java:655)
> at java.base/java.net.ServerSocket.implAccept(ServerSocket.java:631)
> at java.base/java.net.ServerSocket.implAccept(ServerSocket.java:588)
> at java.base/java.net.ServerSocket.accept(ServerSocket.java:546)
> at org.apache.spark.api.python.PythonWorkerFactory.createSimpleWorker(PythonWorkerFactory.scala:179)
> 15 more
> 23/05/27 22:29:16 WARN TaskSetManager: Lost task 0.0 in stage 11.0 (TID 17) (DESKTOP-SHEBUHK executor driver): org.apache.spark.SparkException: Python worker failed to connect back.
> at org.apache.spark.api.python.PythonWorkerFactory.createSimpleWorker(PythonWorkerFactory.scala:192)
> at org.apache.spark.api.python.PythonWorkerFactory.create(PythonWorkerFactory.scala:109)
> at org.apache.spark.SparkEnv.createPythonWorker(SparkEnv.scala:124)
> at org.apache.spark.api.python.BasePythonRunner.compute(PythonRunner.scala:166)
> at org.apache.spark.api.python.PythonRDD.compute(PythonRDD.scala:65)
> at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.computeOrReadCheckpoint(RDD.scala:364)
> at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.iterator(RDD.scala:328)
> at org.apache.spark.scheduler.ResultTask.runTask(ResultTask.scala:92)
> at org.apache.spark.TaskContext.runTaskWithListeners(TaskContext.scala:161)
> at org.apache.spark.scheduler.Task.run(Task.scala:139)
> at org.apache.spark.executor.Executor$TaskRunner.$anonfun$run$3(Executor.scala:554)
> at org.apache.spark.util.Utils$.tryWithSafeFinally(Utils.scala:1529)
> at org.apache.spark.executor.Executor$TaskRunner.run(Executor.scala:557)
> at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1144)
> at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:642)
> at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:1623)
> Caused by: java.net.SocketTimeoutException: Accept timed out
> at java.base/sun.nio.ch.NioSocketImpl.timedAccept(NioSocketImpl.java:694)
> at java.base/sun.nio.ch.NioSocketImpl.accept(NioSocketImpl.java:738)
> at java.base/java.net.ServerSocket.implAccept(ServerSocket.java:690)
> at java.base/java.net.ServerSocket.platformImplAccept(ServerSocket.java:655)
> at java.base/java.net.ServerSocket.implAccept(ServerSocket.java:631)
> at java.base/java.net.ServerSocket.implAccept(ServerSocket.java:588)
> at java.base/java.net.ServerSocket.accept(ServerSocket.java:546)
> at org.apache.spark.api.python.PythonWorkerFactory.createSimpleWorker(PythonWorkerFactory.scala:179)
> 15 more
>
> 23/05/27 22:29:16 ERROR TaskSetManager: Task 0 in stage 11.0 failed 1 times; aborting job
> Traceback (most recent call last):
> File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
> File "C:\Spark\spark-3.4.0-bin-hadoop3\python\pyspark\rdd.py", line 2836, in take
> res = self.context.runJob(self, takeUpToNumLeft, p)
> File "C:\Spark\spark-3.4.0-bin-hadoop3\python\pyspark\context.py", line 2319, in runJob
> sock_info = self._jvm.PythonRDD.runJob(self._jsc.sc(), mappedRDD._jrdd, partitions)
> File "C:\Spark\spark-3.4.0-bin-hadoop3\python\lib\py4j-0.10.9.7-src.zip\py4j\java_gateway.py", line 1322, in **call**
> File "C:\Spark\spark-3.4.0-bin-hadoop3\python\pyspark\errors\exceptions\captured.py", line 169, in deco
> return f(*a, **kw)
> File "C:\Spark\spark-3.4.0-bin-hadoop3\python\lib\py4j-0.10.9.7-src.zip\py4j\protocol.py", line 326, in get_return_value
> py4j.protocol.Py4JJavaError: An error occurred while calling z:org.apache.spark.api.python.PythonRDD.runJob.
> org.apache.spark.SparkException: Job aborted due to stage failure: Task 0 in stage 11.0 failed 1 times, most recent failure: Lost task 0.0 in stage 11.0 (TID 17) (DESKTOP-SHEBUHK executor driver): org.apache.spark.SparkException: Python worker failed to connect back.
> at org.apache.spark.api.python.PythonWorkerFactory.createSimpleWorker(PythonWorkerFactory.scala:192)
> at org.apache.spark.api.python.PythonWorkerFactory.create(PythonWorkerFactory.scala:109)
> at org.apache.spark.SparkEnv.createPythonWorker(SparkEnv.scala:124)
> at org.apache.spark.api.python.BasePythonRunner.compute(PythonRunner.scala:166)
> at org.apache.spark.api.python.PythonRDD.compute(PythonRDD.scala:65)
> at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.computeOrReadCheckpoint(RDD.scala:364)
> at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.iterator(RDD.scala:328)
> at org.apache.spark.scheduler.ResultTask.runTask(ResultTask.scala:92)
> at org.apache.spark.TaskContext.runTaskWithListeners(TaskContext.scala:161)
> at org.apache.spark.scheduler.Task.run(Task.scala:139)
> at org.apache.spark.executor.Executor$TaskRunner.$anonfun$run$3(Executor.scala:554)
> at org.apache.spark.util.Utils$.tryWithSafeFinally(Utils.scala:1529)
> at org.apache.spark.executor.Executor$TaskRunner.run(Executor.scala:557)
> at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1144)
> at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:642)
> at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:1623)
> Caused by: java.net.SocketTimeoutException: Accept timed out
> at java.base/sun.nio.ch.NioSocketImpl.timedAccept(NioSocketImpl.java:694)
> at java.base/sun.nio.ch.NioSocketImpl.accept(NioSocketImpl.java:738)
> at java.base/java.net.ServerSocket.implAccept(ServerSocket.java:690)
> at java.base/java.net.ServerSocket.platformImplAccept(ServerSocket.java:655)
> at java.base/java.net.ServerSocket.implAccept(ServerSocket.java:631)
> at java.base/java.net.ServerSocket.implAccept(ServerSocket.java:588)
> at java.base/java.net.ServerSocket.accept(ServerSocket.java:546)
> at org.apache.spark.api.python.PythonWorkerFactory.createSimpleWorker(PythonWorkerFactory.scala:179)
> 15 more
>
> Driver stacktrace:
> at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler.failJobAndIndependentStages(DAGScheduler.scala:2785)
> at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler.$anonfun$abortStage$2(DAGScheduler.scala:2721)
> at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler.$anonfun$abortStage$2$adapted(DAGScheduler.scala:2720)
> at scala.collection.mutable.ResizableArray.foreach(ResizableArray.scala:62)
> at scala.collection.mutable.ResizableArray.foreach$(ResizableArray.scala:55)
> at scala.collection.mutable.ArrayBuffer.foreach(ArrayBuffer.scala:49)
> at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler.abortStage(DAGScheduler.scala:2720)
> at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler.$anonfun$handleTaskSetFailed$1(DAGScheduler.scala:1206)
> at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler.$anonfun$handleTaskSetFailed$1$adapted(DAGScheduler.scala:1206)
> at scala.Option.foreach(Option.scala:407)
> at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler.handleTaskSetFailed(DAGScheduler.scala:1206)
> at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGSchedulerEventProcessLoop.doOnReceive(DAGScheduler.scala:2984)
> at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGSchedulerEventProcessLoop.onReceive(DAGScheduler.scala:2923)
> at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGSchedulerEventProcessLoop.onReceive(DAGScheduler.scala:2912)
> at org.apache.spark.util.EventLoop$$anon$1.run(EventLoop.scala:49)
> at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler.runJob(DAGScheduler.scala:971)
> at org.apache.spark.SparkContext.runJob(SparkContext.scala:2263)
> at org.apache.spark.SparkContext.runJob(SparkContext.scala:2284)
> at org.apache.spark.SparkContext.runJob(SparkContext.scala:2303)
> at org.apache.spark.api.python.PythonRDD$.runJob(PythonRDD.scala:179)
> at org.apache.spark.api.python.PythonRDD.runJob(PythonRDD.scala)
> at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
> at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:75)
> at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:52)
> at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:578)
> at py4j.reflection.MethodInvoker.invoke(MethodInvoker.java:244)
> at py4j.reflection.ReflectionEngine.invoke(ReflectionEngine.java:374)
> at py4j.Gateway.invoke(Gateway.java:282)
> at py4j.commands.AbstractCommand.invokeMethod(AbstractCommand.java:132)
> at py4j.commands.CallCommand.execute(CallCommand.java:79)
> at py4j.ClientServerConnection.waitForCommands(ClientServerConnection.java:182)
> at py4j.ClientServerConnection.run(ClientServerConnection.java:106)
> at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:1623)
> Caused by: org.apache.spark.SparkException: Python worker failed to connect back.
> at org.apache.spark.api.python.PythonWorkerFactory.createSimpleWorker(PythonWorkerFactory.scala:192)
> at org.apache.spark.api.python.PythonWorkerFactory.create(PythonWorkerFactory.scala:109)
> at org.apache.spark.SparkEnv.createPythonWorker(SparkEnv.scala:124)
> at org.apache.spark.api.python.BasePythonRunner.compute(PythonRunner.scala:166)
> at org.apache.spark.api.python.PythonRDD.compute(PythonRDD.scala:65)
> at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.computeOrReadCheckpoint(RDD.scala:364)
> at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.iterator(RDD.scala:328)
> at org.apache.spark.scheduler.ResultTask.runTask(ResultTask.scala:92)
> at org.apache.spark.TaskContext.runTaskWithListeners(TaskContext.scala:161)
> at org.apache.spark.scheduler.Task.run(Task.scala:139)
> at org.apache.spark.executor.Executor$TaskRunner.$anonfun$run$3(Executor.scala:554)
> at org.apache.spark.util.Utils$.tryWithSafeFinally(Utils.scala:1529)
> at org.apache.spark.executor.Executor$TaskRunner.run(Executor.scala:557)
> at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1144)
> at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:642)
> 1 more
> Caused by: java.net.SocketTimeoutException: Accept timed out
> at java.base/sun.nio.ch.NioSocketImpl.timedAccept(NioSocketImpl.java:694)
> at java.base/sun.nio.ch.NioSocketImpl.accept(NioSocketImpl.java:738)
> at java.base/java.net.ServerSocket.implAccept(ServerSocket.java:690)
> at java.base/java.net.ServerSocket.platformImplAccept(ServerSocket.java:655)
> at java.base/java.net.ServerSocket.implAccept(ServerSocket.java:631)
> at java.base/java.net.ServerSocket.implAccept(ServerSocket.java:588)
> at java.base/java.net.ServerSocket.accept(ServerSocket.java:546)
> at org.apache.spark.api.python.PythonWorkerFactory.createSimpleWorker(PythonWorkerFactory.scala:179)
> 15 more

How I can resolve this error and get 3 rows displayed of csv file

Comment: The problem is not the take(n) command, it's your Python/Spark setup. Your first try works because it doesn't send any task to Spark workers, but your second try with take(n) fails because that method is distributed to Spark workers. Try to open cmd and type "python" to see if it runs. Also check related environment variables like PYTHON_PATH, PYSPARK_PYTHON